# SQL query to delete top item

Tags: sql-server

situation im trying to run this query, i want to delete the the most recent data i've saved in the a table.

```
DELETE from JOBORDER2 Where ddates in (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM JOBORDER2 Where cjobno = '45' ORDER BY ddates DESC);
```

but i got this error. **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
DELETE from JOBORDER2
Where ddates in (
    SELECT TOP 1 ddates
    FROM JOBORDER2
    Where cjobno = '45'
    ORDER BY ddates DESC);
```

The idea is that you're trying to return a set of (1) "ddates".

---

### Explanation

Let's assume that the top "ddates" was '11/30/2012'. Then your query would be equivalent to:

```
DELETE from JOBORDER2
Where ddates in ('11/30/2012');
```

which makes sense. With "*", you were trying to do something nonsensical. There was a rowset in parentheses, and even if there were only one row, you were dealing with more than one column. Which column did you want to compare to?

Comment: it works...can you explain how this query works...and what wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't like the star. Try:

```
DELETE from JOBORDER2 Where ddates in
      (SELECT TOP 1 ddates 
       FROM JOBORDER2 
       Where cjobno = '45' 
       ORDER BY ddates DESC);
```